# Chart data exported to an Apps Script webapp is null

Tags: html, google-apps-script, null, client-server

I have a Google Sheet that I’m using a database for projects my team is working on. What I want to do is use that data to build out different screens on a Google Site. For example, I have been able to add a drop-down list that shows all of the active projects. When a project is selected, an HTML table is returned and displayed.

Now what I’m trying to add is a Gantt chart to the client HTML, with data pulled from the same Google Sheet. I've extrapolated a lot from what I was able to do to display the teams and used [the gviz documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) as a resource for the chart info. Most of my code works well, but I'm having trouble sending the chart data from the Sheets side to the client HTML.

Within my chart building code, I have a `Logger.log` statement, that shows that `chartData` is an `Array` and that it has the data I am expecting:

```
function buildChart(project) {
  var detailsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Details");
  var details = detailsSheet.getRange(2, 1, detailsSheet.getLastRow(), detailsSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  // get the list of teams working on the selected project
  var teams = getTeamsFromProjects(project, details);  // Works, not shown.

  // get the list of teams, without the category
  var sendTeams = new Array();
  for (l in teams) {
    var lRow = teams[l];
    sendTeams.push(lRow[0]);
  }

  // get the projects that the teams are working on
  var projectList = getProjectsFromTeams(sendTeams, details);  // Works, not shown.

  var chartData = getChartDataFromProjects(projectList, details); // Works, not shown.
  Logger.log(chartData);  // this shows that my data is there, in an array

  return chartData;
}
```

Within the webapp's HTML, I have a `console.log("HTML: " + HTML)` that correctly shows the returned HTML (from a .gs function, `displayTeams()`, and it looks correct.  Also within the HTML I have a `console.log("chart data: " + chartData)` that should show the returned array. However, the console says that that `chartData` is NULL.

My question is, why is `chartData` being returned (or at least written to the webapp's console log) as NULL, when I can see from the Apps Script `Logger.log()` statement -- just before it’s returned -- that the data is correctly an array?

Some of my relevant HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 5px solid White;
    }
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      // get the list of Open Projects for the Drop Down
      $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildProjectList)
          .getProjects();
      });

      function buildProjectList(options) {
        var list = $('#projectList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          list.append('<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
        }
      }

      // function called when a Project is selected from the Drop Down
      function showResults() {
        var selectedProject = $('#projectList').val();
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayTeams)
          .buildTeams(selectedProject);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart)
          .buildChart(selectedProject); //THIS IS MY PROBLEM STATEMENT
      }

      // add the teams to the div
      function displayTeams(html) {
        console.log(“html: “ + html);
        $('div.results_div').html(html);
      }

      // add the chart to the div (I HOPE)
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});

      function drawChart(chartData) {
        console.log("chart data: " + chartData); // chartData is missing here
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Resource');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
        data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

        data.addRows(chartData);

        var options = {
          height: 400,
          gantt: {
            trackHeight: 30
          }
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementByClassName("chart_div"));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Select a Project from this list<br><br>

    Projects:<br>
      <select onchange='showResults();' id="projectList" name="project"></select>
      <br>
    <div class="results_div"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are sending incompatible datatypes: per the [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) documentation, requests with `Date`s will fail.

My preferred method for `google.script.run` communication is to 1) send all `Date`s as milliseconds, via `Date().getTime()`, as this will also avoid timezone issues and browser-dependent datestring parsing differences. In the client then, you can remap your input data back to a `Date` object by calling `new Date(milliseconds_value)`, i.e.

```
function successHandler(rectangularArrayData) {
  // Array indices of column values that need to be converted back to Date objects.
  const dateIndices = [0, 3, 8 /**, etc... */];
  // In general, pass your received data into a transformation function. This particular
  // example assumes you only need to remap milliseconds to Date objects.
  const chartData = rectangularArrayData.map(function (row) {
    return row.map(function (col, index) {
      // If this column index should be a date, make it a Date from the milliseconds input.
      // Otherwise, do nothing to it.
      return (dateIndices.indexOf(index) === -1) ? col : new Date(col);
    });
  });
  ...
}
```

and 2) serialize it to a JSON string before sending it. Sometimes you're just sending too complex of an object, and converting it to a string via (`JSON.stringify`) before `return` helps ensure it doesn't get mangled on the wire. In the client, your success handler just needs to reinstantiate it via `JSON.parse()`.

There are a couple other things you do (like ill-advised and non-portable [`for...in` iteration of `Array`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea), [using `new Array()` instead of `[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array), or performing multiple comparisons to check a specific variable for one of several text values instead of using the `Array#indexOf` method) that can be improved, but they're outside the scope of your question and not the source of your issue.

Comment: Can't send a Date; I can't believe I missed that one!  Actually, I can believe I missed that one, but I still feel silly for missing it.  Okay, so now I'm sending the milliseconds back, by using getTime() when adding it to the array (and I can see that it's in the console).  But the Gantt chart builder is expecting a Date; how do I convert those two times back to a Date, so that the chart can accept them?

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional comments!  I'm getting all of the data now, and my Gantt chart is rendering correctly.  As for your other suggestions; thank you very much.  I'm not a developer by any stretch; just slowly teaching myself a few things as I need them.  I know I'm not efficient in what I'm doing, and that there are usually better ways.  I'll take a look at what you've mentioned, and see what I can learn to keep getting better.  Thanks again.