# Contents of a spreadsheet are not displayed in the deployed Apps Script webapp

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I've tried to do an example of the [3rd tutorial on this ctrlq page](https://ctrlq.org/code/19954-html-service-google-scripts), in which we display the content of a spreadsheet on a web page. Here are my files which I simply entered - I didn't activate anything, I just did *Publish* -> *Deploy as web app*

I expect to see all of the [spreadsheet's values](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k_kj98U__0Bk44gh0qRFpaVx0ru3sN1pSPGiMQwimxo), but instead nothing is shown:
[image]

***Code.gs***

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Dynamic Webpage");
  return html; 
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}

function getData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1k_kj98U__0Bk44gh0qRFpaVx0ru3sN1pSPGiMQwimxo").getSheets()[0];
  return sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
<body>
 <div id="data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

***script_js.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<script>

    window.onload = function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
    }

    function showData(data){
      var html = "";
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        html += "<br>" + data[i].join(":");
      }
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to the script project](https://script.google.com/d/1oNA9C9l3euyCImHSiDSjqc9ni7QcfBj-ajbAUS2vyAHT5iY9dOh14MTS/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: No need to make snippets if the code does not run in one. Just indent 40 spaces or use the snippet and remove the line beginning with `<!-- begin snippet:` after pressing TIDY

Comment: Only certain data types can be returned from the server to the client. Consider returning JSON instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I've edited the code. So I will be impossible to show my spreadsheet in the web page because withe the example of ctrlq I thought I will be possible. We can use JSON to show the spreadsheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a Gantt chart in Google Sites with Google Sheet data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686187/building-a-gantt-chart-in-google-sites-with-google-sheet-data)

Comment: Thank you but it's a simple Google spreadsheet it does not use a database :)

Comment: @anamaria did you read my answer to that question? Or did you just read the question?

Comment: Thank you I'm sorry , I've read only the question^^

Comment: @anamaria since I originally posted that link to the question which solves your issue, I have edited its question to be more clear. Please confirm: is your issue solved by the suggested duplicate?

Comment: @tehhowch thank you. No I don't know exactly how to modify it from yesterday I am re-reading the post do I have Date() and I need to use new Array() ? and for JSON I don't see where it's used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** as @tehhowch pointed out [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687783/3789527) is the correct solution here.

For your case you should make these changes, `getData()`:

```
function getData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1k_kj98U__0Bk44gh0qRFpaVx0ru3sN1pSPGiMQwimxo").getSheets()[0];
  return JSON.stringify(sheet.getDataRange().getValues()); // return value as Json
}
```

And `showData(data)`:

```
function showData(data) {
      var arr = JSON.parse(data);
      var html = "";
      for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        html += "<br>" + arr[i].join(":");
      }
      document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
    }
```

Comment: You can absolutely pass a 2d array via `google.script.run`. However, because OP has `Date` objects in the array, which are explicitly identified as not communicable by documentation, the OPs code fails. See the linked post (of which this question is a duplicate) for relevant links.

Comment: @tehhowch You're right, thanks! I wasn't aware of the `Date` limit