# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, canvasjs

I am facing an issue when updating the datapoints of CanvasJS chart, and the error message says

> “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getTime’ of undefined”.

I tried also make it an object like this

```
var parLabels = JSON.stringify(labels);     
var obj = JSON.parse(parLabels);
```

It still didn't work.

**index.html**

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript>
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showDaily).getData();
});
function showDaily(myObj) {
  var email = myObj.email;
  var entity = myObj.entity;
  var entity = JSON.parse(entity);
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var labels = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < entity.length; i++) {
    var month = new Date(entity[i][0]).getMonth();
    var day = new Date(entity[i][0]).getDate();
    var date = day + " " + monthNames[month];
    var score = entity[i][7];
    if (entity[i][2] != '') {
      if (labels != "") {
        labels = labels + ",{label:" + date + ",y:" + score + "}";
      } else {
        labels = "{label:" + date + ",y:" + score + "}";
      }
    }
  }
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
        text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
    },
    data: [              
    {
        // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [ labels ]
    }
    ]
  });
  chart.render();
}

</script>
```

Comment: You can't pass class objects from Apps Script to HtmlService. So send your dates as milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart data exported to an Apps Script webapp is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686187/chart-data-exported-to-an-apps-script-webapp-is-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CanvasJS, [dataPoints](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/) should be an array of objects. But in your case, it seems to be a string. Try changing `labels` to an array and passing it to dataPoints should work fine.

```
var labels = [];
for (var i = 1; i < entity.length; i++) {
    var month = new Date(entity[i][0]).getMonth();
    var day = new Date(entity[i][0]).getDate();
    var date = day + " " + monthNames[month];
    var score = entity[i][7];
    if (entity[i][2] != '') {   
        labels.push({label: date, y: score });
    }
}
```

then pass it as `dataPoints: labels`.

Comment: It works!! Thanks @Vishwas for helping me solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

`google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});`

To

`google.charts.load('45', {packages: ['corechart']});`

The first argument to google.charts.load is the version name or number, as a string.
If you specify 'current', this causes the latest official release of Google Charts to be loaded.
If you want to try the candidate for the next release, use 'upcoming' instead.
In general there will be very little difference between the two, and they'll be completely identical except when a new release is underway.

This issue is resolved in version 45.

Answer (score -1):

This happens to me when I have **only 1 dataPoint**. It seems to be a bug in version 46, 47 so downgrading to version `45` (as @Pranjali Rastogi suggests) works for me.

Another workaround for me is to specify `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and `hAxis.viewWindow.max` so that the chart can "zoom out" to show multiple hAxis ticks.